# Shift Tab Bar Text to left

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a custom tab bar in flutter. However, I can't find a way to shift the text of each tab bar items to the left to ensure a consistent layout as shown:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/utils/constants/colors.dart';
import '../utils/constants/sizes.dart';

class CustomTabBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomTabBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.tabs,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> tabs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
      indicatorColor: AppColors.primary,
      unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.textSecondary,
      labelColor: AppColors.primary,
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      indicator: CircleTabIndicator(
        color: AppColors.primary,
        radius: 4,
      ),
      tabs: tabs,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(AppSizes.appBarHeight);
}

class CircleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  CircleTabIndicator({required Color color, required double radius})
      : _painter = _CirclePainter(color, radius);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _CirclePainter extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;

  _CirclePainter(Color color, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset circleOffset =
        offset + Offset(cfg.size!.width / 2, cfg.size!.height - radius);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleOffset, radius, _paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might try `labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` or `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`

Comment: @chuanpham It works, thank you. You could post your answer as a solution. I will accept it.

Comment: Do you mind also helping to answer my previous question? It is in another post. I posted 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `zero` padding in the `Tabbar` widget to override the default padding of widget.

```
TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
      indicatorColor: AppColors.primary,
      unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.textSecondary,
      labelColor: AppColors.primary,
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      indicator: CircleTabIndicator(
        color: AppColors.primary,
        radius: 4,
      ),
      tabs: tabs,
    );
```

Comment: Does not work. There is no padding to begin with.

Comment: Set `labelPadding` to EdgeInsets.zero too then.

Comment: Do you mind also helping to answer my previous question? It is in another post. I posted 1 hour ago.